# Configuring cookieless domain while using Google analytics

Tags: apache, google-analytics, subdomain, cookieless

My application is hosted on www.abc.co.in and subdomain which hosts the static content is on static.abc.co.in. After adding google analytics, each request to subdomain also includes cookies. How to avoid this?

Below is the script i added. I have tried various subdomain options like setting to www.abc.co.in and abc.co.in, but this did not work. Currently I am trying 'none' which also did not work.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234545-1'],['_setDomainName', 'none'],['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 50], ['_trackPageview'], 
['_trackPageLoadTime']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Comment: I tried the same for www.example.com and cdn.example.com, if I removed the _setDomainName-command totally, the cookies didn't show up on cdn.example.com (Chrome and FF).

Comment: @Rimbaud: this is not working for me, checked in IE, Chrome. I have removed setDomainName , tried adding domain name www.abc.co.in, etc. Same result

Comment: first, there's no need use sitespeed or trackpageloadtime methods because of they've became default with the script and they've been [deprecated] (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageLoadTime).

you should use '_setDomainName', 'abc.co.in' and then you may differ the domains on Audience > Technology > Hostname

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to use a completely different domain, like "static.abc.co.**net**" for your static content, thus completely cookie free.